# automake --add-missing: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I'm using autotools to compile my source codes,

```
    $:~/Temp/cproject$ autoscan
    $:~/Temp/cproject$ ls
    autoscan.log  configure.scan  main.cpp
    $:~/Temp/cproject$ mv configure.scan configure.ac
    $:~/Temp/cproject$ aclocal
    $:~/Temp/cproject$ automake --add-missing
    configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
    configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
    configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
    configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
    automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output
```

the configure.ac file content is as below:

```
    #                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
    # Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

    AC_PREREQ([2.69])
    AC_INIT([FULL-PACKAGE-NAME], [VERSION], [BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS])
    AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([main.cpp])
    AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

    # Checks for programs.
    AC_PROG_CXX

    # Checks for libraries.

    # Checks for header files.

    # Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

    # Checks for library functions.

    AC_OUTPUT
```

what is wrong with my procedures? why do I get these errors? thanks!

Comment: Not an expert, but the error seems very crystal, you haven't got `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` invocation in `configure.ac`...

Comment: @LPs so how to get AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE invocation in configure.ac?

Comment: [check it](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Public-Macros.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `automake` macros, so of course `automake` is failing. The problem here is that [autoscan is buggy and not useful](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/07/autotools-mythbuster-autoscan-autof-up/).

I can refer you to my [basic tutorial](https://autotools.io/whosafraid.html) to get a default basic support for autotools, if that's what you're looking for.